# Jquery/Javascript: How to prevent time limit reset when refresh?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, time

I'm having a problem with the time limit coz when the page is reload/refresh the time limit reset.

I used this time limit to my online quiz program and I'm using a PHP header('Location:') to move to next question.

Feel free to answer

**HTML**

```
<label id="time">1:00</label>
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
 function startTimer(duration, display) {

        var timer = duration, minutes_left, seconds_left;

        setInterval(function () {

            minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
            seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

            minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
            seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

            display.text(minutes + ":" + seconds);  

            if (--timer < 0) {
                //finished
            }

        }, 1000);

    };

    jQuery(function ($) {

        var time_limit = 60 * 2,

        display = $('#time');

        startTimer(time_limit, display);
    });
```

Comment: JavaScript cant ordinarily keep data between multiple requests, you'll need either help from Cookies or Ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just read the default value from the storage

```
jQuery(function($) {

  var time_limit = (localStorage.getItem('time_remaining_min') * 60) + +localStorage.getItem('time_remaining_sec'),
      display = $('#time');
  time_limit = isNaN(time_limit) ? 2 * 60 : time_limit;

  startTimer(time_limit, display);
});
```

Comment: How to destroy it? Because I want to reset the time if the quiz is done. Thank you very much.

Comment: @VanAdrianCabrera just remove the keys from the storage `localStorage.removeItem('time_remaining_min')`

Comment: I add this code inside script but didn't work:

<script type="text/javascript">
localStorage.removeItem('time_remaining_min');
localStorage.removeItem('time_remaining_sec');
</script>